# Ggiraph doesn't work with circular stacked barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggiraph

Hi and thanks for reading me
I am working with a pie bar chart in ggplot2 and I would like to make it interactive with Ggiraph, but I am not getting this to happen and I do not understand what I am doing wrong, or if it is not possible for this particular case. Anyone know if there is any solution about it?
The code is the following:

```
data <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                        individual = c("INDUSTRIAL","DE COMERCIO INTERIOR",
                                       "DE COMERCIO EXTERIOR",
                                       "DE ATRACCION DE INVERSION EXTRANJERA",
                                       "POLÍTICA DE DESARROLLO PARA LA COMPETITIVIDAD DE LAS MIPYMES","DE MEJORA REGULATORIA",
                                       "EN MATERIA MINERA","DE ABASTO","DE PRECIOS",
                                       "DE PROTECCION AL CONSUMIDOR",
                                       "NACIONAL DE CALIDAD",
                                       "NACIONAL EN MATERIA DE NORMALIZACION, ESTANDARIZACION, EVALUACION DE LA",
                                       "CONFORMIDAD Y METROLOGIA",
                                       "DE INDUSTRIALIZACION, DISTRIBUCION Y CONSUMO DE LOS PRODUCTOS AGRICOLAS, GANADEROS, FORESTALES, MINERALES Y PESQUEROS",
                                       "NACIONAL DE FOMENTO ECONOMICO",
                                       "PARA CREAR Y APOYAR EMPRESAS QUE ASOCIEN A GRUPOS DE ESCASOS RECURSOS EN AREAS URBANAS"),
                             group = c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B",
                                       "B","B","B","C","C","C","C","C"),
                            value1 = c(30L,3L,7L,3L,0L,3L,1L,2L,0L,1L,
                                       7L,5L,1L,12L,0L,4L),
                            value2 = c(10L,0L,2L,0L,0L,6L,0L,0L,0L,11L,
                                       7L,6L,0L,3L,1L,0L),
                            value3 = c(0L,0L,1L,2L,14L,2L,1L,0L,0L,0L,
                                       1L,1L,0L,2L,0L,0L),
                            value4 = c(9L,0L,13L,8L,2L,5L,1L,1L,0L,0L,
                                       0L,1L,2L,2L,0L,0L)
                )
data = data %>% 
  gather(key = "observation", value="value", -c(1,2)) 


empty_bar=2
nObsType=nlevels(as.factor(data$observation))
to_add = data.frame( matrix(NA, empty_bar*nlevels(data$group)*nObsType, ncol(data)) )
colnames(to_add) = colnames(data)
to_add$group=rep(levels(data$group), each=empty_bar*nObsType )
data=rbind(data, to_add)
data=data %>% arrange(group, individual)
data$id=rep( seq(1, nrow(data)/nObsType) , each=nObsType)

# Get the name and the y position of each label
label_data= data %>% group_by(id, individual) %>% summarize(tot=sum(value))
number_of_bar=nrow(label_data)
angle= 90 - 360 * (label_data$id-0.5) /number_of_bar     # I substract 0.5 because the letter must have the angle of the center of the bars. Not extreme right(1) or extreme left (0)
label_data$hjust<-ifelse( angle < -90, 1, 0)
label_data$angle<-ifelse(angle < -90, angle+180, angle)

# prepare a data frame for base lines
base_data=data %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarize(start=min(id), end=max(id) - empty_bar) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(title=mean(c(start, end)))

# prepare a data frame for grid (scales)
grid_data = base_data
grid_data$end = grid_data$end[ c( nrow(grid_data), 1:nrow(grid_data)-1)] + 1
grid_data$start = grid_data$start - 1
grid_data=grid_data[-1,]

rhg_cols <- c("#12A09A", "#1E5C4F", "#941B80", "#F19100")

# Make the plot
p <- ggplot(data) +      
  
  # Add the stacked bar
  ggiraph::geom_bar_interactive(aes(x=as.factor(id), y=value, fill=observation), stat="identity", alpha=0.5) +
  #scale_fill_viridis(discrete=TRUE) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = rhg_cols)+
  # Add a val=100/75/50/25 lines. I do it at the beginning to make sur barplots are OVER it.
  geom_segment(data=grid_data, aes(x = end, y = 0, xend = start, yend = 0), colour = "grey", alpha=1, size=0.3 , inherit.aes = FALSE ) +
  geom_segment(data=grid_data, aes(x = end, y = 50, xend = start, yend = 50), colour = "grey", alpha=1, size=0.3 , inherit.aes = FALSE ) +
  geom_segment(data=grid_data, aes(x = end, y = 100, xend = start, yend = 100), colour = "grey", alpha=1, size=0.3 , inherit.aes = FALSE ) +
  geom_segment(data=grid_data, aes(x = end, y = 150, xend = start, yend = 150), colour = "grey", alpha=1, size=0.3 , inherit.aes = FALSE ) +
  geom_segment(data=grid_data, aes(x = end, y = 200, xend = start, yend = 200), colour = "grey", alpha=1, size=0.3 , inherit.aes = FALSE ) +
  
  # Add text showing the value of each 100/75/50/25 lines
  annotate("text", x = rep(max(data$id),5), y = c(0, 50, 100, 150, 200), label = c("0", "50", "100", "150", "200") , color="grey", size=2 , angle=0, fontface="bold", hjust=1) +
  
  ylim(-25,max(label_data$tot, na.rm=T)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    legend.position = "none",
    axis.text = element_blank(),
    axis.title = element_blank(),
    panel.grid = element_blank(),
    plot.margin = unit(rep(-1,4), "cm") 
  ) +
  coord_polar() +
  
  # Add labels on top of each bar
  geom_text(data=label_data, aes(x=id, y=tot+3, label=individual, hjust=hjust), color="black", fontface="bold",alpha=0.6, size=2, angle= label_data$angle, inherit.aes = FALSE ) 
  
  # Add base line information
  #geom_segment(data=base_data, aes(x = start, y = -5, xend = end, yend = -5), colour = "black", alpha=0.8, size=0.6 , inherit.aes = FALSE )  
  #geom_text(data=base_data, aes(x = title, y = -18, label=group), hjust=c(1,1,0,0), colour = "black", alpha=0.8, size=4, fontface="bold", inherit.aes = FALSE)

p
# interactive plot
girafe(
  ggobj = p, 
  width_svg = 7, height_svg = 4, bg = "#D7E0DA",
  options = list(
    opts_hover(css = "fill:#5eba7d88;cursor:pointer;"),
    opts_hover_theme(css = "fill:red;cursor:pointer;"),
    opts_selection(css = "fill:#5eba7d;cursor:pointer;", only_shiny = FALSE, selected = "J"),
    opts_tooltip(css = "background-color:white;padding:5px;border-radius:2px;border: black 1px solid;color:black;")
  )
  
)
```

## UPDATE

Now I use geom_col (geom_col_interactive) but when I exported the object to girafe() nothing appears in the viewfinder

The code is the following:

```
p <- ggplot(data) +      
  geom_col_interactive(aes(x=as.factor(id), y=value, fill=observation), stat="identity", alpha=0.5) +
  scale_fill_manual_interactive(values = rhg_cols)+
  annotate("text", x = rep(max(data$id),5), y = c(0, 50, 100, 150, 200), label = c("0", "50", "100", "150", "200") , 
           color="grey", size=2 , angle=0, fontface="bold", hjust=1) +
  ylim(-25,max(label_data$tot, na.rm=T)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    legend.position = "none",
    axis.text = element_blank(),
    axis.title = element_blank(),
    panel.grid = element_blank(),
    plot.margin = unit(rep(-1,4), "cm") 
  ) +
  coord_polar() +
  geom_text_interactive(data=label_data, aes(x=id, y=tot+3, label=individual, hjust=hjust), color="black", fontface="bold",alpha=0.6, 
            size=2, angle= label_data$angle, inherit.aes = FALSE ) 

p
    girafe(
  ggobj = p, 
  width_svg = 7, height_svg = 4, bg = "#D7E0DA",
  options = list(
    opts_hover(css = "fill:#5eba7d88;cursor:pointer;"),
    opts_hover_theme(css = "fill:red;cursor:pointer;"),
    opts_selection(css = "fill:#5eba7d;cursor:pointer;", only_shiny = FALSE, selected = "J"),
    opts_tooltip(css = "background-color:white;padding:5px;border-radius:2px;border: black 1px solid;color:black;")
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are ggplot issues in your code, for example, geom_bar should not be used with a `y`, use geom_col instead.

With a simple example, here is how to do (from https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/128-ring-or-donut-plot.html)

```r
# load library
library(ggplot2)
library(ggiraph)

# Create test data.
data <- data.frame(
  category=c("A", "B", "C"),
  count=c(10, 60, 30)
)

# Compute percentages
data$fraction = data$count / sum(data$count)

# Compute the cumulative percentages (top of each rectangle)
data$ymax = cumsum(data$fraction)

# Compute the bottom of each rectangle
data$ymin = c(0, head(data$ymax, n=-1))

# Make the plot
p <- ggplot(data, aes(ymax=ymax, ymin=ymin, xmax=4, xmin=3, fill=category)) +
  geom_rect_interactive(aes(tooltip = paste(category,count), data_id = category)) +
  coord_polar(theta="y") + # Try to remove that to understand how the chart is built initially
  xlim(c(2, 4)) # Try to remove that to see how to make a pie chart

girafe(
  ggobj = p, 
  width_svg = 7, height_svg = 4, bg = "#D7E0DA",
  options = list(
    opts_hover(css = "fill:#5eba7d88;cursor:pointer;"),
    opts_hover_theme(css = "fill:red;cursor:pointer;"),
    opts_selection(css = "fill:#5eba7d;cursor:pointer;", only_shiny = FALSE, selected = "J"),
    opts_tooltip(css = "background-color:white;padding:5px;border-radius:2px;border: black 1px solid;color:black;")
  )
  
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I followed the advice and removed some parameters from the ggplot code, however I still can't get it to work with girafe (), may I still be missing something? I updated the code in the original question

Comment: Yes you are missing something, you did not add any interactive aes to your calls!